# Store json object into php session?

Tags: php, json, session

How I can store a JSON object into a php session variable?

Here are an example about what I'm trying to do:

```
var jsonObject={ "menu":
{
    "intro":{
        "intosub":"sub_1"
    }
    "vis":{
        "visub":"sub_2"
    }
}

var string=JSON.stringify(jsonobject);
var phpcode="<?php 

$_SESSION["jsonObject"]=
"
phpcode+=string+"?>";
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you've understand how php works..

Comment: You can't mix and match Javascript and PHP like that, if you're creating an object in javascript you wish to store in session you need to pass it to PHP. Look up Ajax

Comment: can you give me an example, please!

Comment: `var string=JSON.stringify(jsonobject)` - that doesn't even look like valid PHP code

Answer (score 0):

First off - the $_SESSION variable cannot be accessed on the client side(with JS).

You need to send your data to the server and use some server side code to store the sent data in $_SESSION.

[Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) is one way to send data to the server.

This is using the [jQuery Post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) shorthand method.

```js
    // Client side code in Javascript

    var jsonObject={ "menu":
    {
        "intro":{
            "intosub":"sub_1"
        },
        "vis":{
            "visub":"sub_2"
        }
    };

    $.post("control.php", jsonObject, function (returnedData)    {
        console.log(returnedData); 
    });
```

```php
    // Server Side PHP code in "control.php"
    <?php 

    if (isset($_POST['menu'])) {
        $_SESSION['obj'] = $_POST['menu'];
        // these echo commands will output to the 'returnedData' variable
        // that can be used in JS
        echo $_SESSION['obj']['intro']['intosub'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $_SESSION['obj']['vis']['visub'];


    }
    // the output in the browser console would be
    // sub_1
    // sub_2
```

#### Note:

As pointed out by @aabbccsmith using this code would open your server side to manipulation via client-site javascript. Please take this into account and validate all input taken from a front-end client.

Comment: This code will allow the setting of any variable in session in the backend. Whilst a good example, this code should never be used in a production environment as it will allow a potential attacker to set potentially sensitive values on the backend!

Answer (score 0):

You can store a JSON into PHP session like this:

```
$_SESSION["yourobject"] = json_encode($input);
```

The issue in your case is that you are defining the JSON in your browser and you want to store it on your server. Since these are two very different applications, quite often on very different and maybe even distant machines, you cannot do it right away.

You will need to send a request to the server and pass your JSON as a request parameter. Read here about sending AJAX requests: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-ajax-call-from-javascript/